# How to make scrollable TogglerBar?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, dialog-window

Consider the following `TogglerBar`:

```
selectionDialog[list_] := 
 DialogInput[{choice = {}}, 
  Column[{Row[{"Do something:"}], 
    TogglerBar[Dynamic[choice], list, Appearance -> "Vertical"], 
    Button["OK", DialogReturn[choice]]}]]
```

Consider some list:

```
list = Table["Phrase" <> (i // ToString), {i, 1, 100, 1}];

selectionDialog[list]
```

The given list is long, and it does not fit TogglerBar since the latter is not scrollable. Could you please tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Why not make a rectangular grid instead?

Comment: `Appearance -> "Vertical" -> {5, Automatic}` will produce a grid  5 rows with the required number of columns

Comment: @CarlWoll : I may have many hundreds of elements in the list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap `TogglerBar` with [`Pane`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pane.html) and use desired settings for `ImageSize` and [`Scrollbars`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scrollbars.html):

```
selectionDialog[list_] := 
 DialogInput[{choice = {}}, 
  Column[{Row[{"Do something:"}], 
    Pane[TogglerBar[Dynamic[choice], list, Appearance -> "Vertical"], 
     ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}, Scrollbars -> {False, True}], 
    Button["OK", DialogReturn[choice]]}]]

list = Table["Phrase" <> (i // ToString), {i, 1, 100, 1}];

selectionDialog[list]
```

[image]

Comment: @JohnTaylor - You can put a grid inside this pane (e.g., `Appearance -> "Vertical" -> {Automatic, 5}`) with associated change to `ImageSize`. This will limit the scrolling required for large lists.